# Looping a string split from an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

My program currently scans a .txt files content and stores it into an array. I now need to split the string within the array without converting the whole array to one long string. Currently I have:

```
    List<String> content_lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) 
        {
          content_lines.add(scan.nextLine());
        }

        String[] string_array = content_lines.toArray(new String[0]);

        for (int i=0; i < string_array.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(string_array[i]);
        }

        /*The code is fine up until this point, this is where the split 
        occurs. Rather than storing each line that it has split, it 
        continues to overwrite the previous line.*/

        String[] content_split=null;
        for (int i=0; i<string_array.length; i++) 
        {
        content_split = string_array[i].split(":"+" ");

        }
```

The code is fine up until the point where the split occurs. Rather than storing each line that it has split, it continues to overwrite the previous line. When I debug the program the new content_split array keeps overwriting and only contains that last three pieces of data from the split.

The .txt file contains data like this:

```
          Firstname Lastname
          test1 : 1000 : 200
          test2 : 1300 : 200
          test3 : 1600 : 210
```

Comment: That is because you're overwriting it? `content_split = string_array[i].split(":"+" ");`

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your Question. In general, you should [edit] the Question to *clarify the Question*, but not to include an Answer within the Question. You should create your own Answer with the code you used to solve your problem, then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to accepting your own answer). When you have solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: This was previously rolled back to rev #2, which was essentially removing the question and putting an answer in its place, which doesn't make a lot of sense. It also invalidates the answers below, so I've moved it back to rev #1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
String[][] content_split = new String[string_array.length][]; // create 2d array
for (int i=0; i<string_array.length; i++){
     content_split[i] = string_array[i].split(" : "); // store into array and split by different criteria
}
```

Which leaves you with a 2D array of your split content.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
content_split = string_array[i].split(":"+" ");
```

to:

```
content_split = string_array[i].split("\\s*:\\s*");
System.out.println(content_split[0] + " " + content_split[1] + " " + content_split[2]);//assuming you have 2 colons every line.
```

Now output would be:

```
test1 1000 200
test2 1300 200
test3 1600 210
```

if you are not sure of how many columns i might have, you could do the following:

```
content_split = string_array[i].split("\\s*:\\s*");
for(int i=0; i<content_split.length; i++)
    System.out.print(content_split[i] + " ");
System.out.println();
```

Comment: you need to leave a blank line between code blocks and non-code blocks.