# How do you create a string array list from a text file in java?

Tags: java, file, arraylist, text

I am trying to create a program that will allow a teacher to grab students from a roster, then throw them into random groups. I plan on creating an arraylist from the text file that has a bunch of student names on it. I need help pulling the students names from the file and then inserting their names into an array list.

Here is where the array would come in handy (other places too but program is not complete):

```
 try {
     System.out.println("Please enter the name of the student that you would like to add to the file as \"Last name, First name\"");
     PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName, true));  
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     String s = sc.next();
     outputStream.println(s);
     sc.close();
     outputStream.close();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
```

I also need to involve a couple of classes in this program so I created this class, my idea with this is one is that I can create an open variable for the students that are on file.

```
public class Name {

    private String studentName;

    public Name() {
    }

    public Name(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName; 
    }


    public String getstudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    public void setstudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

}
```

And here is the text file with some names, the challening part for me is that there is a comma separating the names (maybe I should remove that?) :

```
 Ospina, Bryan
 Patel, Krupa
 Preite, Nicholas   
 Quigley, Kevin
 Rubet, Aaron   
 Said, Abanoub
 Sidler, Allen
 Thiberge, Daniel
 Thota, Raajith
 Tripathi, Rashi    
 Tsang, Johnny
 Velovic, Joseph
 Victor, Samuel
 Whitted-Mckoy, Eric
 Wu, Michelle
```

Edit: Condensed the code

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is far too much code here.  In order to make it clear exactly where your problem is, please remove any code that is not directly causing your problem, and if you can reduce it to ten lines or less, I will consider retracting the downvote.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @JoeC Sorry about that! I was afraid that without all of the code I would not provide enough context to the nature of the program. I went ahead and removed all of the stuff that isn't directly related :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is alternative way how to accomplish your task:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Scan {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "text.txt";
        List<Name> names = new ArrayList<>();

        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(fileName))) {
            while (scan.hasNext())
                names.add(new Name(scan.nextLine().replace(",", "")));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(names);
    }

    public static class Name {
        private final String studentName;

        public Name(String studentName) {
            this.studentName = studentName;
        }

        public String getstudentName() {
            return studentName;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return studentName;
        }
    }
}
```

By using class `Scanner` you can read a file as follow: `Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(fileName))`. Read file line by line: `scan.nextLine()` until end of file: `while (scan.hasNext())`. Create `new instance` of `Name`: `new Name(scan.nextLine().replace(",", ""))` and add it into `list`: `names.add(...)`. To remove `,` used `replace(",", "")` method of `String` class.

Comment: This worked wonderfully! I appreciate the explanation of the code!

Answer (score 1):

Using a Stream, which you will not be able to use for your homework...

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        final String filename = "whatever";

        List<Name> list =
            Files.lines(Paths.get(filename))   // Strings, lines in the file
            .map(line -> line.split(","))      // String[], split by ,
            .map(split -> split[1] + split[0]) // String, joined again
            .map(Name::new)                    // Name, make a Name object from String
            .collect(Collectors.toList());     // collect into a List<Name
    }

    public static class Name {
        private final String studentName;
        public Name(String studentName) {
            this.studentName = studentName;
        }
        public String getstudentName() {
            return studentName;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check:

[Manipulate data from a file and then store it into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393833/manipulate-data-from-a-file-and-then-store-it-into-an-array)

I had the exact same.

Answer (score -1):

> How do you create a string array list from a text file in java?

You need to read until the End Of File, I am showing one of the approaches using the BufferedReader until the end of the file.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("pathToYourFile"));
String input = null;
String [] splittedInput = null;
String fullName = null;
List<Name> names = new ArrayList<>(); // Maintaining all the names
while((input = br.readLine()) != null) { // Until the End
 splittedInput = input.split(",");
 fullName = splittedInput[1] + splittedInput[0]; // Since file stoes lastname,firstname
  names.add(new Name(fullName));
}

//Now names list contains all Name Object
```